# Apex method in Apex job and Apex Flex Queue Monitor screen

Tags: apex, apex-flex-queue

I went through release notes and reference books but didn't find anything about this "Apex Method". Has any one idea how to get value in Apex Method?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apex Method column lists down the methods having **future annotations**. If you have a simple Apex job, that column is not really relevant.